# How can i display Name of a team in list of players mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i've searched for 2 days over the internet finding the answer to my problem but didn't the right answer.

these are my classes

```
public class Player
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public Team Team { get; set; }

    public int TeamId { get; set; }

public class Team
{
    public int TeamID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Player> Players { get; set; }
```

i added in my viewmodels the same ->

```
public class CreatePlayerVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamId")]
    public Team Team { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Team")]
    [Display(Name = "Team")]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

public class ListPlayerVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamId")]
    public Team Team { get; set; }

    public int TeamId { get; set; }
```

and my view for list of players is like this ->

```
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Team)
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.YellowCard)
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RedCard)
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Goal)

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Team.Name)
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.YellowCard)
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RedCard)
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Goal)
```

and the homeController

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Players()
    {
        List<Player> p1 = Player.GetPlayers();

        List<ListPlayerVM> p2 = new List<ListPlayerVM>();

        foreach (Player p in p1)
        {
            p2.Add(new ListPlayerVM(p.ID, p.Name, p.FirstName, p.Team , p.TeamId, p.Goal, p.YellowCard, p.RedCard));
        }

        return View(p2);
    }
```

and the CreateController

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreatePlayer(CreatePlayerVM model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            Player player = new Player(model.FirstName, model.Name, model.Team, model.TeamId ,0, 0, 0);
            player.InsertPlayer();

        }
        PopulateTeamsDropDownList(model.TeamId);
        return View(model);
    }
```

How can i display my teamName in my list of created players? tired of searching over the internet hopefully somebody can help me out!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ELCJ.jpg

```
    public static Player GetPlayer(int id)
    {
        using (LeagueDBContext ctx = new LeagueDBContext())
        {
            return ctx.Players.Where(a => a.ID == id).SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Grts

Comment: It not clear what your asking here - your `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Team.Name)` will display the name of the team (assuming your query is loading it). And remove your `[ForeignKey("TeamId")]` attributes on your view models (they are EF specific attributes and have nothing to do with view models)

Comment: i've editted the post, with a screen of what i'm getting.. it doesn't display the name.

Comment: Then the `Name` property of `Team` does not contain any data! You may need to use a `.Include(x => x.Team)` in your query because you have not marked the `Team` property as virtual in your data model (your have not shown the code for your `GetPlayers()` method). And what does your `CreatePlayer()` method have to do with your question?

Comment: editted the post again with the getplayers() method. Is it there i want to use Include?

Comment: `return ctx.Players.Include(a => a.Team).Where(a => a.ID == id).SingleOrDefault();`

Comment: i already thank you for youre time , i got this error now : Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1660 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Then I suggest you google _Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type_ (your probably missing the correct `using` statements

Comment: Thx Got it! Thank you for youre help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your are not lazy loading your team data. You must use virtual to lazy load it. Your Player model should look like this:

```
public class Player
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }

    public int TeamId { get; set; }
}
```